# SQL Server Interest calculations on transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm looking for advice on best way to build a compound interest module in SQL server. Basic set up:
Table: Transactions {TransID, MemberID, Trans_Date, Trans_Code, Trans_Value).
Table: Interest {IntID, Int_eff_Date, Int_Rate}

In the interest table, there may be different rates with an effective date - can never have an over lapping date though. For example:

```
Int_Eff_Date       Int_Rate
01/01/2016         7%
01/10/2016         7.5%
10/01/2017         8%
```

I want to calculate the interest based on the transaction date and transaction value, where the correct interest rate is applied relative to transaction date.

So if Table transaction had:

```
TransID   MemberID    Trans_Date    Trans_Value
1         1            15/04/2016    150
2         1            18/10/2016    200
3         1            24/11/2016    200
4         1            15/01/2017    250
```

For transID 1 it would use 7% from 15/04/2016 until 30/09/2016 (168 days) from 1/10/2016 to 09/01/2017 it would use 7.% and then from 10/01/2007 to calculation date (input parameter) it would use 8%.

It would apply similar methodology for all transactions, add them up and display the interest value.

I'm not sure if I should use cursors, UDF, etc.

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: Ideally I would like to write an interest transaction to the transaction table at the end of each month (Trans_code 2). across all memberID's. I would also like a UDF for mid-month calculations so the inputs would be memberID, Calculation date). Output would be Transaction Total (sum of transactions for period, Interest until Calculation Date).

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the Result Table should look like?

Comment: Using a basic formula to calculate the interest of Principal * (1 + Rate / 365)^days. For each memberID show the total principal (sum of transactions for period), Interest calculated (sum of interest for each transaction over period), total (sum of principal and Interest)

Answer (score 0):

This should provide an outline of what you're trying to do.

```
--Build Test Data
CREATE TABLE #Rates(Int_Eff_Date DATE
                    , Int_Rate FLOAT)
CREATE TABLE #Transactions(TransID INT
                            ,MemberID INT
                            ,Trans_Date DATE
                            ,Trans_Value INT)

INSERT INTO #Rates     
VALUES  ('20160101',7)
        ,('20161001',7.5)
        ,('20170110',8)

INSERT INTO #Transactions
VALUES 
(1,1,'20160415',150)
,(2,1,'20161018',200)
,(3,1,'20161124',200)
,(4,1,'20170115',250)


;WITH cte_Date_Rates
    AS
    (
    SELECT 
        S.Int_Eff_Date
        ,ISNULL(E.Int_Eff_Date,'20490101') AS "Expire"
        ,S.Int_Rate
    FROM
        #Rates S 
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Int_Eff_Date 
                        FROM #Rates E 
                        WHERE E.Int_Eff_Date > S.Int_Eff_Date
                        ORDER BY E.Int_Eff_Date) E 
    )
SELECT
    T.*
    ,R.Int_Rate
FROM
    #Transactions T 
        LEFT JOIN cte_Date_Rates R
            ON
            T.Trans_Date >= R.Int_Eff_Date
            AND
            T.Trans_Date < R.Expire
```

Comment: Thank you - so this correctly displays the correct interest rate as at the transaction date. Let's take a single transaction. I would need to work out the days within each interest period and apply the correct rate. So Transaction of 100 on date 28-11-2016 - the starting rate is 7.5%. IK would need to check if there is another interest rate after this date, if there isn't, then the calculation is simple, we take number of days (calc date to trans date) and calculate interest using the rate identified.

Comment: .... If there is another interest rate, then we need to work out the days from trans date to next interest rate, apply the rate in the formula, store result in variable. then test again if there is another rate change, if yes, work out number of days between interest rate changes, wehat the rate is, plug it into formula and add interest result to variable. Keep doing this until we get to calculation  date with no interest rate change. Make sense?